# What might be causing my problem to access user variables in Rules?

Tags: 7, rules, tokens

I use the module [Rules link event](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_linkevent) to trigger a rule based on visited path. The problem I have that in condition I need to use user variables but get an error - variable user is not defined. If I try php condition and use `global $user`, I get `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in eval() and Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in eval()`

What could be the problem here?

Comment: try a first condition on the user, for example a user of a specific role, or with the permission to view content, etc. This should make the variable available for future conditions

Comment: @Geoff I tried it as my first option. I checked if current user is member of xy group. But rules gave error  - variable user is not defined.

Comment: are you using it with Commerce? that's what it was designed for - if not, take a look at [Rules Link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1365658) instead

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the reason might be that is causing your problem. But something that you could do to make this work, for sure, is like so:

- Add a Rules Action "Fetch entity by id", whereas you want to fetch the user entity, and where you use the `uid` of the "current-user". For any subsequent Rules Action, you then have all fields of that user available as tokens.
- Enable the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module, which allows you to specify Rules Conditions as part of Rules Actions. Using that technique, you can then like "move" any of your existing Rules Conditions (ie the ones where you need those user variables, as per your question). In doing so, you can then use any of the tokens that you made avaiable via the preceeding Rules Action "Entity has field".

BTW, no dangerous PHP code (stored in your database) needed to get this to work ...

***Easy, no***?